# merging xml based on conditions

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have two xml's just say like this. As below

XML:

```
<APPLICATION>
    <AC>
            <CLASS Name="Hello1" Capt="do1"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello2" Capt="do2"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello5" Capt="do5"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello8" Capt="do8"/>
    </AC>

    <BO>
            <ITEM Id="1" DefaultValue="name1"/>
            <ITEM Id="3" DefaultValue="name3"/>
            <ITEM Id="11" DefaultValue="name11"/>
            <ITEM Id="12" DefaultValue="name12">
                    <VAL>
                            <REASON Id="Job1" SecondOne="Hallo"/>
                    </VAL>
            </ITEM>
    </BO>
```

XMl2:

```
<APPLICATION>
    <AC>
            <CLASS Name="Hello1" Capt="dodo1"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello2" Capt="dodo2"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello3" Capt="dodo3"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello9" Capt="dodo9"/>
    </AC>
    <CARS Wheel="Fore" Default="45x255xZ"/>
    <CARS Wheel="BACK" Default="45x255xZ"/>
    <CARS Wheel="SPARE" Default="45x255xZ"/>
    <BO>
            <ITEM Id="1" DefaultValue="namename1"/>
            <ITEM Id="3" DefaultValue=""/>
            <ITEM Id="9" DefaultValue="name11"/>
            <ITEM Id="10" DefaultValue="name12">
                    <VAL>
                            <REASON Id="Job1" SecondOne="Hallo"/>
                    </VAL>
            </ITEM>
    </BO>
```

I need an output as below:

Condition: I want a condition on Id, such a way - When Two 'ID' on different XMl's are equal, irrespective of other attributes. Same ID values Should be printed as One irrespective of their attributes (Whether different or not). I need output as below

MergedXml:

```
<APPLICATION>
       <AC>
             <CLASS Name="Hello1" Capt="do1"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello2" Capt="do2"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello5" Capt="do5"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello8" Capt="do8"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello1" Capt="dodo1"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello2" Capt="dodo2"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello3" Capt="dodo3"/>
            <CLASS Name="Hello9" Capt="dodo9"/>
      </AC>
       <CARS Wheel="Fore" Default="45x255xZ"/>
      <CARS Wheel="BACK" Default="45x255xZ"/>
      <CARS Wheel="SPARE" Default="45x255xZ"/>
      <BO>
          <ITEM Id="1" DefaultValue="name1"/>
          <ITEM Id="3" DefaultValue="name3"/>
          <ITEM Id="11" DefaultValue="name11"/>
            <ITEM Id="12" DefaultValue="name12">
           <ITEM Id="9" DefaultValue="name11"/>
            <ITEM Id="10" DefaultValue="name12">
      </BO>
```

I need to write in C#

Comment: What have you tried? Why is it tagged as both C# and VB.Net when you need to write it in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this should get you in the ballpark.

```
    Dim x1 As XElement
    Dim x2 As XElement
    x1 = <APPLICATION>
             <AC>
                 <CLASS Name="Hello1" Capt="do1"/>
                 <CLASS Name="Hello2" Capt="do2"/>
                 <CLASS Name="Hello5" Capt="do5"/>
                 <CLASS Name="Hello8" Capt="do8"/>
             </AC>

             <BO>
                 <ITEM Id="1" DefaultValue="name1"/>
                 <ITEM Id="3" DefaultValue="name3"/>
                 <ITEM Id="11" DefaultValue="name11"/>
                 <ITEM Id="12" DefaultValue="name12">
                     <VAL>
                         <REASON Id="Job1" SecondOne="Hallo"/>
                     </VAL>
                 </ITEM>
             </BO>
         </APPLICATION>

    x2 = <APPLICATION>
             <AC>
                 <CLASS Name="Hello1" Capt="dodo1"/>
                 <CLASS Name="Hello2" Capt="dodo2"/>
                 <CLASS Name="Hello3" Capt="dodo3"/>
                 <CLASS Name="Hello9" Capt="dodo9"/>
             </AC>
             <CARS Wheel="Fore" Default="45x255xZ"/>
             <CARS Wheel="BACK" Default="45x255xZ"/>
             <CARS Wheel="SPARE" Default="45x255xZ"/>
             <BO>
                 <ITEM Id="1" DefaultValue="namename1"/>
                 <ITEM Id="3" DefaultValue=""/>
                 <ITEM Id="9" DefaultValue="name11"/>
                 <ITEM Id="10" DefaultValue="name12">
                     <VAL>
                         <REASON Id="Job1" SecondOne="Hallo"/>
                     </VAL>
                 </ITEM>
             </BO>
         </APPLICATION>

    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    ie = From x1id In x1.<BO>.<ITEM>, x2id In x2.<BO>.<ITEM>
         Where x1id.@Id = x2id.@Id
         Select x2id

    If ie.Count > 0 Then
        ie.Remove()
        x1.<AC>.LastOrDefault.Add(x2.<AC>.Elements)
        x1.<AC>.LastOrDefault.AddAfterSelf(x2.<CARS>)
        x1.<BO>.LastOrDefault.Add(x2.<BO>.Elements)
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It will help for my part.